# Empty space in filename issue while downloading file

Tags: java, download, httpresponse

Following java code is being used to download a requested log file throgh a web application:

```
    protected HttpServletResponse response;
....

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    String filename = OrgName + ".log";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + filename);
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    os.write(getFile());
    os.close();
```

Problem comes when `OrgName` contains a space like "Xyz Pvt Ltd", in this case file will be download with name "Xyz" rather than "Xyz Pvt Ltd.log".The part of name after 1st space is ignored. Please note that the file is downloaded correctly, it is only the name which is not showing up correctly. Is there anything I am doing wrong? or Is it a standard behavior?

**Environment:** Struts 2, Jboss 5.1.0, Mozilla Firefox 3.5.3

Comment: I think is browser dependent. Just tried in IE(8.0) Chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I found your problem. Just set the file name string as quoted

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use a encoding for spaces You can look into apache base64 encoder, I remember that spaces get encoded to %20% and thus on decoding you would be able to retrieve the filename with spaces.

Comment: If you do that it will take %20% as a part of file name itself and won't show it as space char.