# File name not showing completely

Tags: c#, asp.net

On our asp.net project, the users can download some files. Here's the code i'm using for the download part:

```
String localUpload = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PastaEditais"].ToString();                    
String nomeArquivo = licitacao.getEdital();                
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(localUpload + nomeArquivo);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + licitacao.getEdital());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName);
Response.End();
```

IF the filename doesn't have any white spaces on it, it appears normally.

For example: if the name is ATI_06-07-2014.txt, it will appear just like this.
But if it has white spaces, only part of the name is shown on the download dialog box.

ATI 06-07-2014.txt will be shown only as 'ATI'

How can i fix this?

Comment: Parhaps you need quotation marks around the filename after `filename=`?

Comment: add quote to filename http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005834/empty-space-in-filename-issue-while-downloading-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes to the filename:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + licitacao.getEdital() + "\"");
```